# Can not get unmatched rows from three tables in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I can not get unmatched row from three tables in mysql.
rd table has 3 rows of venueid 88. But my query return only two rows.
My desired output is:

[image: desired output]

```
bookingId|bookingMeetingRoomId|bookingVenueId|venueId|rdId|morningTotalGuest|shiftId|
|98       |80                  |88            |88     |80  |99              |137|
|null    |null                |null           |88     |81  |null            |130|
|null     |null                |null          |88     |82  |null            |null|



SELECT a.booking_id,a.booking_meeting_room_id,a.booking_venue_id,rd.venue_id,rd.rd_id,
      rd.rd_img_name,rd.rd_rhname, rd.rd_max_capacity,
        --  shift.shift_id,
        (
        SELECT SUM(booking_total_guest)
        FROM dv_bookings
        WHERE booking_shift_name LIKE '%morning%' AND booking_venue_id = 88 AND booking_checkin = '2018-04-06' AND a.booking_meeting_room_id=dv_bookings.booking_meeting_room_id) AS 'morning_total_guest',
        (
        SELECT SUM(booking_total_guest)
        FROM dv_bookings
        WHERE booking_shift_name LIKE '%dinner%' AND booking_venue_id = 88 AND booking_checkin = '2018-04-06' AND a.booking_meeting_room_id=dv_bookings.booking_meeting_room_id) AS 'dinner_total_guest',
        (
        SELECT SUM(booking_total_guest)
        FROM dv_bookings
        WHERE booking_shift_name LIKE '%lunch%' AND booking_venue_id = 88 AND booking_checkin = '2018-04-06' AND a.booking_meeting_room_id=dv_bookings.booking_meeting_room_id) AS 'lunch_total_guest'
        FROM dv_bookings a
        RIGHT JOIN
        (
        SELECT rd_id, rd_img_name, rd_rhname,rd_max_capacity, rd_room_size,venue_id
        FROM dv_room_details
        WHERE venue_id = 88) rd ON 
        a.booking_meeting_room_id = rd.rd_id
         AND a.booking_venue_id = 88 AND a.booking_checkin= '2018-04-06'
        right JOIN

        (
        SELECT shift_id,shift_room_id,shift_venue_id,shift_morning_start_time,shift_morning_end_time,shift_lunch_start_time,shift_lunch_end_time,shift_dinner_start_time,shift_dinner_end_time
        FROM dv_venue_shift_time_table
        WHERE shift_venue_id = 88 AND shift_day_name='Fri') shift 
        -- WHERE shift_id is null) shift
        ON rd.rd_id = shift.shift_room_id 
        -- on rd.rd_id = a.booking_meeting_room_id
        -- on shift.shift_room_id = a.booking_meeting_room_id
        -- AND a.booking_venue_id = 88 AND a.booking_checkin= '2018-04-06'
        GROUP BY a.booking_meeting_room_id;
```

[image: The output is as follows:]

Comment: please explain your problem more clearly (i understand: 1 row missing) ...and plz (better) indent/format the query.

Comment: booking table has 1 row matched, shift table has 2 rows  and rd table has 3 rows but I want to show all matched and unmatched.

Comment: ...sry, i still dont understand/read the query, but sounds like you want a `LEFT JOIN` (..where u use a `RIGHT` one).

Comment: yes, but i can not make it, when left join, unmatched rows from right table not shows, so i used right join but then all unmatched rows from left table e.g. rd table not shows. That's my problem.

Comment: If you want to get everything irrespective of match, why not use full join?

Comment: I've used full join but not worked. And in mysql full join not work.